# Wrong value when I use lisbox.get(ACTIVE)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class LayerSelector(tk.Listbox):

def __init__(self, master, mod):
    tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master)
    self.mod = mod
    self.bind("<Button-1>", self.select_event)
    self.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.change_order)

def select_event(self, event):
    layer = self.get(tk.ACTIVE)
    print(layer)
    if layer != "":     # if something is selected
        self.mod.current_layer = layer

def change_order(self, event):
    pass


def get_order(self):
    order = self.get(0, tk.END)
    return list(order)
```

My function `select_event` doesn't work properly. The first time I click on an item, it gives me always the first item and when I click on another, it gives me the previous item I clicked on.

Comment: That is because your bindings happen before the default bindings.  Do some research on "binding tags". If you want to get something when it is selected, bind to `<<ListboxSelect>>` instead.

Comment: @BryanOakley Same issue with <<ListboxSelect>> instead of <Button-1> even if I add                                                                                             "btags = self.files.bindtags()                                                          self.bindtags(btags[1:] + btags[:1])"                                                       
Before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems. First, you're creating a custom binding that fires before the default binding, so it will always display the state of the widget *before* the click.

Second, if you want to call a function when something is selected, you should bind to `<<ListboxSelect>>` as that event is triggered *after* the selection has been changed.

The third problem is that you are getting the active element. The active element is not necessarily the selected element. It can be, but it's not guaranteed to be. To get the selection, use the `get` method along with the `curselection` method.

For example:

```
class LayerSelector(tk.Listbox):

    def __init__(self, master, mod):
        tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master)
        self.mod = mod
        self.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.select_event)
        self.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.change_order)

    def select_event(self, event):
        selection = self.curselection()
        layer = self.get(selection[0])
        print(layer)
        if layer != "":     # if something is selected
            self.mod.current_layer = layer
```